# cordova - Unable to save password in HTML form despite autocomplete attribute

Tags: vue.js, cordova, autocomplete

I want to save password like in chrome in my cordova application.
I use Quasar for development: https://quasar.dev/
Here is my form:

```
<q-form @submit="soumettre">
      <q-card flat>
        <q-card-section class="row q-col-gutter-sm">
          <q-input
            v-model="email"
            class="col-12"
            label="Email"
            icon="mail"
            type="email"
            autocomplete="username"
          />
          <champs-texte
            v-model="password"
            class="col-12"
            label="Password"
            icon="key"
            type="password"
            autocomplete="current-password"
          />
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-actions>
          <btn
            label="Connect"
            type="submit"
          />
        </q-card-actions>
      </q-card>
    </q-form>
```

On Chrome, I have a popup that appears to save the password but not in the Cordova application.

How can I do to resolve this problem?

I try to autocomplete props and form html.

Comment: Did you try adding the name attribute to the tag? For example `<input autocomplete="..." name="...">`  from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845584/adding-autocomplete-to-input-fields-on-cordova-android-and-ios-app

Comment: I try to add name attribute and I have the same problem